# how to inject controller in routeprovider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I am quite new to the angularJS, here is my suggested problem.

I have a route.js file which only stores route related stuff. 
looks like this.

```
var app = angular.module('ontology', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/abduction', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/abduction.html',
            controller: 'axiomFormCtrl',
        })
        .when('/logicDifference', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/logicDifference.html',
            controller: 'axiomFormCtrl',
        })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

and I have another file ontology.js which has all the controller and one of the controller is axiomFormCtrl.

```
var app = angular.module('ontology', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

app.controller('axiomFormCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    console.log("in axiom form ctrl....");
});
```

Now if I ran the program, it will say that `axiomFormCtrl is undefined`. I am not sure how I can resolve the dependency problem.

Comment: Do you load the ontology.js scrip in your index.html file ?

Comment: Have you included a reference to your script in your html file?

Comment: It looks like you're defining the application twice... that might be causing an issue.

Comment: What Mike said. You are overwriting the first definition, the one with the controller, with the second one, the one with the `$routeProvider`. To get a reference to an already defined app you need to use `angular.module('ontology')` - note the lack of a second parameter, the list of dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you are including the script to `ontology.js` in your HTML:

```
...
<script src="routes.js"></script>
<script src="ontology.js"></script>
```

Second, you are defining your module twice, here:

```
var app = angular.module('ontology', ['ngRoute']);
```

And here:

```
var app = angular.module('ontology', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);
```

So, define it one time, with all of the required modules.  This might be done in a file called `app.js` (which you'll also need to include in your HTML):

app.js

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('ontology', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);
})();
```

And then in all of your other files that will use the `ontology model`, use the same syntax, minus the second parameter (the array of other modules):

routes.js

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('ontology');

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/abduction', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/abduction.html',
                controller: 'axiomFormCtrl',
            })
            .when('/logicDifference', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/logicDifference.html',
                controller: 'axiomFormCtrl',
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]);
})();
```

And ontology.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('ontology');

    app.controller('axiomFormCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        console.log("in axiom form ctrl....");
    });
})();
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the root cause. Thanks.